# Remove major mode key bindings in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I installed a new major mode (sunrise commander), and I want to reset all its predefined key bindings.
Although I can use

```
(add-hook 'sr-mode-hook
    '(lambda ()
    (define-key sr-mode-map "KEY"        nil)
    ...
))
```

this mode have so many bindings, it's a tag tedious to my taste.

Is there a way to completely reset the key bindings of this major mode in a one-liner or few-liners?

---

EDIT #1:
I tried using these methods as described below:

```
(eval-after-load "sunrise"
  '(setq sr-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap)))
```

OR

```
(add-hook 'sr-mode-hook
    (lambda ()
    (setq sr-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap))))
```

Sadly, neither of them seems to work.

Do I actually need to define a new, empty keymap?
E.g. using

```
(defvar sunrise-keys-mode-map (make-keymap) "sunrise-keys-mode keymap.")
(define-minor-mode sunrise-keys-mode
  "A minor mode so that my key settings override sunrise major mode keymap."
  t " my-keys" 'sunrise-keys-mode-map)
(sunrise-keys-mode 1)
(eval-after-load "sunrise" ;; Fix this line to include the correct library name
  '(setq sr-mode-map (sunrise-keys-mode)))
```

---

EDIT #2:
After a bit of tinkering in the sunrise commander code, I noticed that the sr-mode-map is based on the dired mode map. I disabled both, and it worked perfectly.

```
(eval-after-load "sunrise-commander"
  '(setq sr-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap)
         dired-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap)))
```

For future reference - the above is the only code needed.
make-sparse-keymap is a function that returns an empty keymap (unless provided with an argument, apparently).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cound bind `sr-mode-map` to a newly-created, empty keymap:

```
(setq sr-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap))
```

---

You might need to delay this until after sunrise commander is loaded:

```
(eval-after-load "sc" ;; Fix this line to include the correct library name
  '(setq sr-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap)))
```

Comment: Do I need to add anything else beside the above command? Should I call it from the sr-mode-hook? Because either option didn't work for me:-)

Comment: Calling it from `sr-mode-hook` should work (although it might be a bit overkill, and you would need to set your own key bindings immediately after that)

Comment: Calling it directly in your init file should work, but you might need to delay evaluation after sunrise-commander is loaded (see my edit; maybe this will work better). I don't use sunrise commander, but I have tested this technique with other major modes (such as `python-mode`) and it works well...